# Wordpress rewrite rule (migrate website, redirect all urls)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I couldn't find any post about my exact problem and I'm not smart enough to try&error things on a live website.

So please help.

I want to migrate Website A into Website B and I know that I need to put a rewrite rule into Websites A .htaccess.

the rewrite rule should probably look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websiteA.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteB.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.websiteA.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteB.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My problem is, that the URL structure of website B is different from Website A. Website A is "https://websiteA.de/%postname%/" but Website B is "https://websiteB.de/%category%/%postname%/"

so maybe something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websiteA.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteB.de/%category%/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.websiteA.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.websiteB.de/%category%/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I'm absolutely not sure, I have no Idea and I can't test it on my live page. Can you tell me what the rewrite rule should look like then?

I've looked through the internet for similar problems, but I'm not happy with the results.

Comment: You can't reasonably do this in `.htaccess` if the `%category%` varies and is determined by WordPress. You would need to hardcode each redirect individually. How many URLs are you redirecting? How many different categories? If the `%postname%` is the same on site B and unique then you can potentially look-up the category in WordPress - but this is not something you can do in `.htaccess` (you would obviously need to do the redirect in WordPress itself - which is arguably preferable anyway). To clarify `%catgeory%` is WP terminology - this has nothing to do with Apache/mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thousands of URLs. two different categories.
I also posted this on stackexchange as you already saw for yourself (didn't know it's both the same site) someone told me there to ask at stackoverflow.

Comment: "Stack Exchange" is a network of related sites. You initially posted the question on "WordPress" - questions specific to WordPress development/usage. StackOverflow is more general programming and is generally better suite to `.htaccess` type questions (which is not strictly part of WordPress). However, this is looking more like a WordPress specific question...

Comment: "two different categories" - How many URLs for each? You could potentially redirect one-by-one the smaller category and then redirect everything else to the other category? Do the domains for A and B point to the same place? Or is websiteA.com still pointing to an "old server"?

Comment: WebsiteA is pointing to an old server, yes.
I think the smaller category has around 800 URLs. The other has around 3000

Comment: @MrWhite I'm not sure how this is WP specific as the problem is the same wether it's a WP site or a Joomla site that got migrated

Comment: @TomJNowell Because, ordinarily, IF both domains point to the same (WordPress) server then it would be far more efficient to resolve this in the application (ie. WordPress) than Apache/`.htaccess`. (When WP has determined the request would result in a 404 - due to no category in the URL - then lookup the corresponding category in the DB and issue the redirect - this way it does not impact normal site traffic.) However, since the OP has later stated in comments that the old domain still points to the old server (and there are only two categories) then Apache/`.htaccess` becomes a via option.

Answer (score 0):

> Thousands of URLs. two different categories.
> WebsiteA is pointing to an old server, yes. I think the smaller category has around 800 URLs. The other has around 3000

Since `websiteA.com` is pointing to an old server, you wouldn't really be able (or need) to do this within WordPress. This also allows you to simplify the directives in `.htaccess` since you don't need to check the requested hostname. Since all requests reaching this host are for `websiteA.com`, there's no additional overhead for the server at `websiteB.com`. And since there are "only" two categories it does become a viable option to use `.htaccess`.

However, this does mean you will need to manually specify the URLs for the smaller category (all 800 URLs) unfortunately. You can perhaps generate these directives from a list of the old URLs and a macro in your editor of choice.

For example, in the `.htaccess` file in the root of `websiteA.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect the homepage only to the root
# (I assume the homepage does not have a "category"?)
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.websiteB.com/ [R=301,L]

# (OPTIONAL) Redirect static assets (URLs with a file extension) to the same URL (no "category")
RewriteRule \.(jpg|css|js|pdf)$ https://www.websiteB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# List all 800 URLs for the smaller category ("category-1")
RewriteCond $1 =post-name-001 [OR]
RewriteCond $1 =post-name-002 [OR]
RewriteCond $1 =post-name-003 [OR]
: etc.
RewriteCond $1 =post-name-800
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ https://www.websiteB.com/category-1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect remaining URLs (approx 3000) to the larger category ("category-2")
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ https://www.websiteB.com/category-2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

NB: There is no `OR` flag on the last *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive).

The `$1` backreference contains the URL-path as captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Note that this does *not* start with a slash. I've excluded an *optional* trailing slash from the captured subpattern, so don't include a trailing slash on any of the URLs in the preceding *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives).

**UPDATE:** I modified the regex (`RewriteRule` *pattern*) from `(.+?)/?$` to `^([^/.]+)/?$` as this will be more optimal since the old URLs consisted of a `/%postname%/` only (a single path segment). I'm also assuming the `%postname%` does not contain dots.

That's about the most concise you can do this if using Apache/`.htaccess` at `websiteA.com`.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: @Sascha309 I've updated my answer with a slightly more optimal regex. ie. changed the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `(.+?)/?$` to `^([^/.]+)/?$`.